# Posting to a Facebook page without logging in using C#

Tags: c#, facebook

I've read a lot of posts about how to handle posting to FB without logging in - specifically in my instance to a managed page, some using the defunct "offline_access" method, others relating to tokens.

I've created a token from my graph API  - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

I've also created a little test in some code e.g.

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient("Access_Token"]);
Dictionary<string, object> argList = new Dictionary<string, object>();
argList["message"] = "my message";
fb.Post("mypage/feed", argList);
```

This works perfectly as expected and posts to the page wall in question. If however I log out of Facebook, it doesn't work and in turn throws an error.

```
Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException - #190) 
Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out
```

I'm stuck about why this happens when I've set the permissions correctly in the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer area e.g. "publish_stream", "manage_pages" etc.

I've even assigned the token to an app I've created too which still doesn't help.

Has anyone got an example in C# that illustrates how to post when you are not logged in?

Thanks in advance,

Deeds.

Answer (score 0):

Its may be because of access token validation expired, if you have application Id and Secret key of which you used to generate access token, You can use the following code to extend the access token validation period upto 60 days .

```
public string exchange_access_token(string actoken)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = "xxxxxxxxx",
            client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            grant_type = "fb_exchange_token",
            fb_exchange_token = actoken
        });

        return result;
    }
```

But if you dont have application details you cant do this ...

Comment: I'm getting "This API call requires a valid app_id" yet I've got the app_id and app_secret from the app I'm using to create an access token with.

Comment: If you have valid id of the application it wont throw error, it clearly saying that, this is not the app id which used to create that particular access token. Try with creating new access token and test this code ...

Comment: I've navigated to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and created a token based on the application that relates to the app id and secret key and still getting this - unless the app_id is another setting somewhere else

Comment: Have u created the access token for test accounts or using the access token of application itself ?

Comment: The application itself so I go to developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, I choose the application from the application drop down, click get access token, make sure the manage_pages permissions are set etc. Then I go to the app dashboard page and copy the app id and app secret which I paste into your code snippet and thus the error

Comment: see you have to get the access token for particular test accounts or admin account then you have to try for this

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense to me, I've followed the exampel as shown in http://codeoverload.wordpress.com/2012/02/11/posting-to-facebook-with-c/ it's slighlty old but works fine when you are logged in as soon as I log out it doesn't work and I can't fathom out where to get this illusive access token from - as far as I can see I've already got it and Facebook won't recognise it.